# Grid doesnot show filtering image inside Jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am using Jquery dialog to show radgrid. I have set AllowFilteringByColumn to true which shows the filtering textbox with an image under each column of the radgrid. But as i am using it inside a Jquery Dialog it does not show the image is it becoz of zindex or ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the z-index is the culprit.Increase the z-index of the grid and its filter menu to see whether this makes a difference.